# Insert data into two tables, one depend on another

Tags: codeigniter, sql-insert

For example I have such structure in database:

table1:
[id]
[content]

table2:
[id]
[table1_id]

and I want insert some data at the same time into this two tables, but the problem is with [table1_id] which is primary key from table1. How can I insert it?

Comment: First u must insert into table1 then in table2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to insert the primary key of table 1 into table 2, code igniter has built in helper functions to help with this task.

```
//prepare data for table 1    
$data = array(
   'conent' => 'My content',
);
//insert into table 1
$this->db->insert('table1',$data);

//prepare data for table 2
$data = array(
   'table1_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
);
//insert into table 2
$this->db->insert('table2',$data);
```

Comment: @Sudarshan could you explain how that is different? It looks like the methodology used in this link is identical to that shown above

Comment: See below comment, i think you saw first one. Its better to get latest inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

As you are referring table1_id in table2 so u must insert your table1 fields first. Then you can insert into table2.
Here is what you can do in your controller

```
public function insert(){
   $data['table1_data']=$this->ur_model->insert_table1();
   $latest_id=$this->ur_model->get_latest_id();
   $data['table1_data']=$this->ur_model->insert_table2($latest_id);
}
```

in your model

```
function insert_table1(){
    $data=array(
                'content'=>$this->input->post('content')
          );
    $this->db->insert('table1',$data);
    //better return true on success
}

public function get_latest_id(){
    $sql=$this->db->query("SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM table1");
    return $sql->row_array();
} 

function insert_table2($table1_id){
    $data=array(
               'content'=>$this->input->post('content'),
               'table1_id'=>$table1_id['id']
          );
    $this->db->insert('table2',$data);
}
```

So that you will always get latest id inserted into table1_id.

Comment: I thinking about this solutions before i asked question and I start wondering what if i have really heavy traffic on my site and two users call this function at the same time? It is possible to this order: first user call  so data insert to table1 but in the same time second user call function so again data insert to table1 and first user would have wrong data. The  Ben Broadley answer seems to me better

Comment: check this http://gotoanswer.com/?q=How+to+insert+into+multiple+tables+with+CodeIgniter second post

Comment: the above solution which u accepted works but in primary  key cases if thats not a primary key, that may create problem.

Comment: @Sudarshan I've just tested this code and it doesn't work, looks like theres an error in the get_lastest_id() function. You appear to be running two queries in it and `row` isn't a valid property of a mysql result object in the return statement.

Comment: Yeah sorry I updated now  missed _, but that doesnt mean it wont work mr. @BenBroadley

Comment: @Sudarshan i've got your code working, it wasn't just the _, I'll edit it in a second, whilst this might well be needed under specific conditions, I don't see this as an elegant solution to a simple case as described in the OP.